# How to perform @After for a specific JUnit test case?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm using Espresso to build UI tests. For some test cases I would like to call a specific after step to reset the state in case the script fails.

Is there a way to perform an `@After` step for a single JUnit test case (`@Test`)?
The only solution I can think of is to make a separate test class. But I would like the test cases to be grouped in the same test class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does sound a little odd ;) but ...

- You could add a try/finally to the single test for which you want this *after* behaviour. For example:

  ```
  @Test
  public void testA() {
      try {
          // the body of testA
      } finally {
          // apply the 'after' behaviour for testA 
      }
  }
  ```
- Or, if you really want to use JUnit's `@After` then you could use the [TestName Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules#testname-rule) (since JUnit 4.7) as follows:

  ```
  @Rule
  public TestName testName = new TestName();

  @After
  public void conditionalAfter() {
      if ("testB".equals(testName.getMethodName())) {
          System.out.println("apply the 'after' behaviour for testB");
      }
  }

  @Test
  public void testA() {

  }

  @Test
  public void testB() {

  }
  ```

Comment: upvoted because mentioning TestName rule, it helped me a lot because I was using contiperf